# How to make javadoc comments in overriden methods visible

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, overriding, javadoc

I'm using Eclipse. I want the comments made in the overridden method to appear instead.

Here's an example -

```
enum Foo{
    ITEM{
        /**
          * Arguments must be received in the following order...
          */
        @Override
        void bar(String[] args){...}
    };

    /**
      * Bars the specific args
      * @param args the specific args
      */
    abstract void bar(String[] arags);
}
```

When I have something like the following `Foo.ITEM.bar(...)` and I hover over it, I want to read

> Bars the specific args
>   Arguments must be received in the following order...
>   @args the specific args

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really have Javadocs for individual enum constants' methods.

So, either put the important information into the general method (i.e. `Foo.bar`), or into the documentation of the individual constant (i.e. `Foo.ITEM`).  The methods for the individual constants shouldn't be that different that they require individual comments anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly, this is what `{@inheritDoc}` is for. Place it in the comment body or appropriate tag to get the comment from the superclass/interface declaration.

[Source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html) and relevant excerpt:

> Automatic Copying of Method Comments The Javadoc tool has the ability
>   to copy or "inherit" method comments in classes and interfaces under
>   the following two circumstances. Constructors, fields and nested
>   classes do not inherit doc comments.
>
> Automatically inherit comment to fill in missing text - When a main
>   description, or @return, @param or @throws tag is missing from a
>   method comment, the Javadoc tool copies the corresponding main
>   description or tag comment from the method it overrides or implements
>   (if any), according to the algorithm below. More specifically, when a
>   @param tag for a particular parameter is missing, then the comment for
>   that parameter is copied from the method further up the inheritance
>   hierarchy. When a @throws tag for a particular exception is missing,
>   the @throws tag is copied only if that exception is declared.
>
> This behavior contrasts with version 1.3 and earlier, where the
>   presence of any main description or tag would prevent all comments
>   from being inherited.
>
> Explicitly inherit comment with {@inheritDoc} tag - Insert the inline
>   tag {@inheritDoc} in a method main description or @return, @param or
>   @throws tag comment -- the corresponding inherited main description or
>   tag comment is copied into that spot.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an interface, add the javadoc to the interface, and then use the @Override tag, and it should show up.